# Fire up event when element is inserted to html OL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list `ol` in HTML where I dynamically add new elements after user action.

Is it possible to register a method which will be called after new `li` has been added to list??

Comment: yeah, just call the function after you insert the item..

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. but thats not what I was asking for as with more complex scenario this creates extra logic and more coupling :)

Comment: looking for something like a promise maybe?

Comment: what kind of promise?

Comment: Sort of like a callback. You can just use a callback. see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Mutation Observers**

Other similar answer: [Detect changes in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom)

The following works in Chrome 18+, Firefox 14+, IE 11+, Opera 15+, and Safari 6+ and is documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

```js
function add() {
  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += "<li>added</li>";
}

// Where listening for new <li>s happens
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "Doing something on DOM change.\n";
  });
});

var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

observer.observe(document.getElementById("list"), config);
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
<ol id="list">
  <li>First!</li>
  <li>Second.</li>
  <li>Third...</li>
  <li>fourth......</li>
  <li>fifth :(</li>
</ol>
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. Not sure if browser support isn't a problem tho.

Answer (score 1):

Use a conditional callback.

```js
function addJunk(junkToAdd, callback){
    $("#myList").append("<li>"+junkToAdd+"</li>");
    if("function"===typeof callback) callback();
}

addJunk("junk");
addJunk("stuff");

// but this time i wanna do stuff afterwords
addJunk("things", function(){
    alert("just did some stuff");
});
  
addJunk("items");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id='myList'></ol>
```

Alternatively, you can look into [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

```js
function addJunk(junkToAdd){
    return new Promise(function(callback){
        $("#myList").append("<li>"+junkToAdd+"</li>");
        callback();
    });
}

addJunk("junk");
addJunk("stuff");

// but this time i wanna do stuff afterwords
addJunk("things").then(function(){
    alert("just did some stuff");
});
  
addJunk("items");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id='myList'></ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this [events reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events), I've found there was a [DOMNodeInserted event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events), but it got deprecated. Looks like they're recommending to use [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) now - there're [some examples here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#Example_usage), but I've never tried it. Pay attention to the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#Browser_compatibility) too.

Think twice if you're not overthinking something which is not really need, it could simply just call a function whenever you'd like.